# Move multiple files with the same name into new folders named with the file paths

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a lot of files with the same name stored in many different project folders. I would like to move these files into a new folder, and I'd like to name that folder with the original location of the file.

I currently have this structure:

```
C:\XYZ\Folder 1\File1.txt
C:\XYZ\Folder 2\File1.txt
C:\XYZ\Folder 3\File1.txt
```

And I would like all the `File1.txt` files to be moved to new folders as below:

```
F:\Destination\C_XYZ_Folder 1\File1.txt
F:\Destination\C_XYZ_Folder 2\File1.txt
F:\Destination\C_XYZ_Folder 3\File1.txt
```

I've found it difficult to find and understand what I'm looking for. I can move one file, but beyond that I get prompted to replace the file that was just moved since they all have the same name, and I haven't been able to combine that with creating a new folder with the file location as the name.

Ultimately what I'm trying to do is move multiple files with the same name located in different folders into a new location, but still be aware of the original location of each file. Renaming the file is OK but my file paths are quite long.

Comment: Can you please clarify how will we find these files? Are there are any subfolders of a parent folder we should search?

Comment: [xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) should do, if I understand your question correctly (keeping folder structure): `xcopy /s "C:\XYZ\file1.txt" "F:\Destination\"`

Comment: @Stephan no, I don't think the OP wants this. I think he wants `driveletter_path`

Comment: @double-beep: If I were sure, I would have answered. Maybe that's just what koyeti came up as an idea, maybe it's real requirement. No way for us to know. At least, `xcopy` could handle destination like `F:\Destination\C\XYZ_Folder 1\File1.txt`, which might fit their needs - or not. I's koyeti's turn to clarify now.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Please share your efforts ([edit] the question for that)! Otherwise, this post is a code request, which is clearly off-topic here. Please read the [tour] and also these help articles: [ask], [mcve].

Comment: Thanks for your comments. @double-beep I'm not clear on what you mean - the path would include one parent folder `XYZ`, then the subfolders `Folder 1`, `Folder 2` etc., and this pattern is repeated for parent folder `ABC` for example.

@Stephan the requirement is to move these files, but I would like to be aware of their original location should a particular file be needed to be returned (occurred in the past). Since they all have the same name I thought to separate them into folders with the file path, which I had begun doing manually.

Comment: so instead of `C_XYZ`, `C\XYZ` would be fine?

Comment: Yes that would be fine if Windows allows the character in the folder name. Even without a delimiter would be fine though, as in `CXYZFolder 1` because I can understand the source location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that in `C:\` there is a folder `XYZ` where there are lots subfolders and some of them (or all of them) have `File1.txt` to make a folder and move it there, you may need:

```js
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R "C:\XYZ\" %%A IN (File1.txt) do (
    rem /* Find path of file excluded filename (dp=drive and path): */
    set "drive_path=%%~dpA"

    rem /* In this %%~dpA, replace '\' and ':\' according to OP's requirements: */
    set "formatted=!drive_path:\=_!" & set "formatted=!formatted::=!"

    rem /* Make the folder: */
    md "F:\Destination\!formatted!"

    rem /* Move the file there: */
    move "%%~fA" "F:\Destination\!formatted!"
)
```

The above code made the path in format `F:\Destination\C_XYZ_etc\File1.txt`. As mentioned in comments you may also want:

```js
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /R "C:\XYZ\" %%A IN (File1.txt) do (
    rem /* Find path of file excluded filename (dp=drive and path): */
    set "drive_path=%%~dpA"

    rem /* In this %%~dpA, replace '\' and ':\' according to OP's requirements: */
    set "formatted=!drive_path:\=!" & set "formatted=!formatted::=!"

    rem /* Make the folder: */
    md "F:\Destination\!formatted!"

    rem /* Move the file there: */
    move "%%~fA" "F:\Destination\!formatted!"
)
```

where it will be in format `F:\Destination\CXYZETC\File1.txt`.

If there multiple files you want to check: (using `set /p` [input from user]):

```js
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:files
set /p files=Please enter the files you want to check separated by spaces. Quote all filenames: 
if not defined files (goto:files)

:loop

rem Loop through user input (filenames):
for %%A IN (%files%) do (
    for /R "C:\XYZ\" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        rem /* Find path of file excluded filename (dp=drive and path): */
        set "drive_path=%%~dpB"

        rem /* In this %%~dpB, replace '\' and ':\' according to OP's requirements: */
        set "formatted=!drive_path:\=!" & set "formatted=!formatted::=!"

        rem /* Make the folder: */
        md "F:\Destination\!formatted!"

        rem /* Move the file there: */
        move "%%~fB" "F:\Destination\!formatted!"
    )
)
```

With arguments (easier):

```js
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:argument_check
if [%1] == [] (echo Action requires arguments^^! Please rerun from cmd specifying arguments^^! Remember to quote each filename^^! & exit /b 1)

:loop

rem Loop through arguments (filenames):
for %%A IN (%*) do (
    for /R "C:\XYZ\" %%B IN ("%%A") do (
        rem /* Find path of file excluded filename (dp=drive and path): */
        set "drive_path=%%~dpB"

        rem /* In this %%~dpB, replace '\' and ':\' according to OP's requirements: */
        set "formatted=!drive_path:\=!" & set "formatted=!formatted::=!"

        rem /* Make the folder: */
        md "F:\Destination\!formatted!"

        rem /* Move the file there: */
        move "%%~fB" "F:\Destination\!formatted!"
    )
)
```

Comment: These worked for me, thanks for your clear explanations

Answer (score 0):

[xcopy](https://ss64.com/nt/xcopy.html) has the `/s` switch to recursively scan subfolders. The following recreates the folderstructure (just the folders, where `file1.txt` is present) to `F:\Destination\C\`:

```
xcopy /s "C:\XYZ\file1.txt" "F:\Destination\C\"
```

copies

```
C:\XYZ\Folder 1\File1.txt
C:\XYZ\Folder 2\File1.txt
C:\XYZ\Folder 3\File1.txt
C:\XYZ\File1.txt
C:\XYZ\Folder 1\Subfolder\File.txt
```

to

```
F:\Destination\C\XYZ\Folder 1\File1.txt
F:\Destination\C\XYZ\Folder 2\File1.txt
F:\Destination\C\XYZ\Folder 3\File1.txt
F:\Destination\C\XYZ\File1.txt
F:\Destination\C\XYZ\Folder 1\Subfolder\File1.txt
```

Comment: This also works when I added `del /s "C:\XYZ\File1.txt"` to get closer to my requirements, thank you very much.

Comment: `robocopy` has  `/mov` and `/move` switches, but a slightly different syntax.